# The probability of making a word out of letters

Tags: probability, combinatorics, permutations

Say we have the word PENCIL, out of which we are making random strings of letters without repeating them.

What is the probability of making a string that neither starts with P nor ends with L?

The way I tried this is by calculating $P(A') = 1-\frac{4!}{6!} = \frac{29}{30}$, since you should be able to permute the middle letters in 
 "P _ _ _ _ L". However, the answer from my book is $\frac{7}{10}$.

At this point I'm not even sure whether I'm wrong or the result in the book...

Comment: You are forgetting the strings that start with P or end with L, but not both.

Comment: @TonyK This may just be an english issue, but I believe the strings you are saying would neither start with P nor end with L

Comment: @AlanAbraham: I meant what I said. mteXD is counting the strings ("P _ _ _ _ L") that start with P and end with L, in order to subtract them from the total; but this is forgetting all the strings that start with P _or_ end with L (but not both). These should also be subtracted from the total.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The probability of a letter starting with $P$ is $P(P)=\frac{5!}{6!}$

The probability of a letter ending with $L$ is $P(L)=\frac{5!}{6!}$

The probability of a letter starting with $P$ and ending with $L$ is $P(P\cap L)=\frac{4!}{6!}$

The probability of a letter starting with $P$ or ending with $L$ is $P(P\cup L)=\frac{5!}{6!}+\frac{5!}{6!}-\frac{4!}{6!}=\frac{3}{10}$

Finally,

Probability of making a string that neither starts with P nor ends with L is

$P(P\cup L)'=1- P(P\cup L)=1-\frac{3}{10}=\frac{7}{10}$